# How do I install Python modules on macOS Sierra

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, module, installation

I'm having trouble installing the lxml module on my computer. I'm running macOS Sierra and using Python 3.6.0 from python.org. I've been using PyCharm Edu to work on some projects from a book I just finished and am now branching off into working on my own projects and can't figure out where or what to type to install any modules.

As far as I can tell I have pip installed and should be able to install modules using "pip install lxml" but if I try that in PyCharm, or IDLE, or the Terminal (where I don't exactly know where to enter this) I get "SyntaxError: invalid syntax".

Comment: Do it in any plain command lines console, **don’t** type python first, just type `pip install lxml`

Comment: Okay, so I just opened a new terminal window and typed 'pip install lxml' and it returned '-bash: pip: command not found'.

Comment: Is pip in your PATH? If not, type `python3 -m pip install lxml` instead, in the way you ran the other command

Comment: I figured it out! I typed `pip3 install lxml` and that did it.